# How to change date of each input of each td by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops, datepicker

I intend to change date of another input field by selecting a date from an input field by `jquery datepicker` UI.

So my html layout is:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>1st</th><th>2nd</th><th>3rd</th><th>4th</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input c="y" d="5" /></td>
        <td><input c="d" d="2" /></td>
        <td><input c="m" d="2" /></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my jQuery code (assuming this code is using jquery-ui plug in) for changing date is:

```
$('input').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onClose: function(date){
  var c = $(this).attr('c');
  var d = parseInt($(this).attr('d'),10);  

  var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
     if(c=='y'){   
        date2.setFullYear(date2.getFullYear()+d);
     }
     if(c=='d'){   
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+d);
     }
     if(c=='m'){   
        date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth()+d);
     }
  $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').datepicker('setDate', date2);
}
});
```

What is happening here, If an user select a date in input field of `1st Column`, it is adding 5years to the selected date and put the result in the input field of `2nd Column`. Then if the user select/change a date in input field of `2nd Column`, it is adding 2days to the selected date of `2nd Column` and putting that date in the input field of `3rd Column` and so on.

But I have to set a way also, so that if an user select a date from input field of `1st Column`, it will add 5years to the selected date and output that date in `2nd Column`, then it will add more 2days with that (intial selected date + 5years date) date of `2nd Column` and output it in the `3rd Column` and this process will be continued until the last `td` of that concerned `tr` reached.

I am unable to figure out such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is correct. All you need to do is to iterate through each input element and determine the values of c's and d's and add it to the next td.

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>1st</th><th>2nd</th><th>3rd</th><th>4th</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input c="y" d="5" /></td>
        <td><input c="d" d="2" /></td>
        <td><input c="m" d="2" /></td>
        <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('input').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function (date)
        {
            var date2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('input').each(function (i, op)
            {
                var c = $(this).attr('c');
                var d = parseInt($(this).attr('d'), 10);

                if (c == 'y') {
                    date2.setFullYear(date2.getFullYear() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'd') {
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'm') {
                    date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + d);
                }
                $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            });            
        }
    });
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6h6zj59v/

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as my expectation. But I could not understand the use of argument of i and op in `$('input').each(function(i,op)`. It will be my pleasure if you explain me the specific point of use of those arguments (i,op) in this function. It will help me to understand the code better. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually 'i' represents index and 'op' represents the properties. I added those parameters in the hope of using them but didn't need them. You may ignore them